# RecordId was sent over the bridge, but it's not cached in watermelondb

Tags: android, react-native, mobile-development, watermelondb

While working on sync api implementation, data was not getting synced with the backend server. As I debug the issue using `react-native log-android` for android apk it is giving the below error:

```
{ [Diagnostic error: Record ID customEvent#eeqpmwlxhbfspqje was sent over the bridge, but it's not cached]
                             │ framesToPop: 2,
                             │ name: 'Diagnostic error',
                             │ line: 686,
                             │ column: 197,
                             └ sourceURL: 'index.android.bundle' }
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem which is caused by using integer as the _id. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Ryker Are you deleting collection or data of collection also?

Comment: Nope I was just creating tables but I actually just figured it out (probably not best practice haha). I just changed the id column type from auto incrementing ID to `text` on the backend to match WatermelonDB. 
I'm sure there would've been a way for me to keep it as an auto incrementing and just convert the changes query IDs into strings using lodash but I couldnt quite figure that out yet.